# How can I get the pneumatic brace on my screen door to release?

Tags: screens

I have a screen door that has a pneumatic brace that keeps the door open.  It is currently stuck open and I'm trying to press the release mechanism, but I can't get it to release.

Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: [Sledgehammer!](http://www.google.com/url?source=imglanding&ct=img&q=http://www.cheshirecatstudios.com/reviews/dementium-2/sledgehammer.jpg&sa=X&ei=9TJOT6KfNYXY0QG0gtHgAg&ved=0CA0Q8wc&usg=AFQjCNEndMVbPSJxKM0mU_jO6-94SoT5MQ)

Comment: A picture would allow folks to see the type of release you have.

Comment: Have you tried opening the door further, to relieve the pressure on the locking mechanism?

Comment: My glass exterior door works the same way Tester101 describes. Push it farther out, then it closes. Alternatively, if you just want to get the door closed for the time being, you could remove the pin holding the cylinder in place on the door frame.

Comment: I removed the pin and cylinder and tried to pull it farther to get it to release.  Still didn't work, but now I can close my door!  Fortunately I have a cylinder on the top of the door still causing it to close.

Comment: Bigger Sledgehammer!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just utilized [Tester101's method](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12609/how-can-i-get-the-pneumatic-brace-on-my-screen-door-to-release/49054#comment17117_12609) of opening the door further and it worked perfectly. Just open the door as wide as it'll go and the locking gizmo disengages.

Answer (score 2):

I've had screen doors that were propped open with the brace and when people try to swing it shut without thinking, they end up bending the little metal brace itself, not allowing it to close. You can usually bend it back with a little shove but it probably won't shut as smoothly as before. If the little metal piece that keeps it open is stuck, then maybe get some pliers and wiggle it some to try and get it to slide back down so you can close the door.

Answer (score 1):

If the bracket that attaches the closing device to the door has a number of settings where you can put a screw, thenDetach the bracket that attaches to the door itself.

Then close the door a little bit and reattach the bracket so that there is a lot more slack to be able to open the door.

Now you should be able to open the door wider and release the latching mechanism